# Static method as library

Tags: c#

I simply use a static method to convert byte to image.
In a multithreaded environment is it safe or should I have to instantiate
every call?

```
 namespace Library
 {

   public static class ByteToImage
   {
      public static Image Convert(byte[] byteArrayIn)
      {
          MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
          Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
          return returnImage;
      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not using anything outside the method so it is thread safe *so long as* nothing is also updating the `byteArrayIn` in another thread.

```
namespace Library
{

   public static class ByteToImage
   {
      public static Image Convert(byte[] byteArrayIn)
      {
          Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
          return returnImage;
      }
   }
 }
```

**UPDATE**

I orignally advices to close the stream. Howeve, as was pointed out in the comments, this particular operation requires the stream to stay open for the lifetime of the Image. [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx)

However, *in general* it is always a good idea to clean up streams in a using block to ensure it is done.

Comment: well, that's just about everything I had to say (now deleted) fully covered ;p

Comment: -1. This will cause Image to fail. You **should not** release the memory stream here as it is the buffer used by image.

Comment: So may I happily use the method on a webserver?

Answer (score 1):

It's not using a shared resources so it's ok so long as nothing is also updating the byteArrayIn in another thread as Colin said

Comment: byteArrayIn is a potential shared resource.

Comment: that's true. Your response is more accurate. I'll just update it to not confuse anyone that read it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are thread safe if they are not using any shared resources.

Yours does not use any shared resource so it is OK - unless somewhere else in the code you are using the same image.

Comment: byteArrayIn is a potential shared resource.